# BorderWidth set to 2px but not showed on page

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm working on an app with react, material-ui. I'm trying to add border to a div but failed. Following is my code

```
<div className={classes.search}>
  ...
</div>
```

```
search: {
  ...
  borderWidth: '2px',
  borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
},
```

I check in chrome and it shows my border parameter is identified by chrome as 2px, but chrome use 0px instead of 2px as final border width. Any ideas on how it happened?

[image]

Comment: This is what dev tools show, when you specified a border-width, but no border-style ... then the _effective_ width of the borders is of course zero.

Comment: You have to set the border-style property, too. For example `border-style: solid`. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

Comment: Thank you guys. it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you missed to set `borderStyle`.

You can set the border style with Material-UI theme like the following.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  search: {
    border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`
  }
});
```